# Postgresql how to change current_date to GMT+5:30 or ISTor Asia/Kolkata timezone

Tags: postgresql, timezone

I am using postgreSQL . I need to find date as `yyyy-mm-dd`.

What I did is as follows:

```
select from current_date;
```

It works fine. But **I need it with respect to Indian timezone ,I mean GMT+5:30/(Asia/Kolkata)**. My datatype in storing column is `date`.

I have tried as:

```
select current_date AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kolkata'
```

What I am getting is timezone as type of output. I need datatype in date.

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
set timezone='Asia/Kolkata'
```

to change `timezone` in PostgreSQL

and If you want to get current date in `yyyy-mm-dd`format within the select query

```
select current_date,to_char(current_date,'yyyy-mm-dd')::date;
```

Comment: thanks buddy. I had solved it by using: `select current_date ::date AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kolkata`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
set timezone to 'Asia/Calcutta'

Answer (score 0):

select date(current_date AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kolkata')